# How to make a grid resize with the window and have a scrollbar in ExtJS 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have seen a lot of similar questions here, but I couldn't solve my problem
Which layout should i use?

so far i tried: layout: 'fit' and autoscroll: true - no result, although i could put them in the wrong place

here is the code:

```
Ext.define('..MyPanel', {
extend: '...ParameterPanel',(which extends Ext.grid.Panel),

initComponent: function () {
    this.grid = Ext.create('...', {flex:1});

    this.items = [
        this.grid   
    ];
    this.callParent();
},
```

Comment: Did you try overflowX:'scroll' or overflowY:'scroll' for horizontal and vertical scrollbars respectively?

Comment: where should i put this configs?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('MyPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
layout: 'fit',

initComponent: function () {
    this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
        flex:1,
        autoScroll: true
    });

    this.items = [
        this.grid   
    ];
    this.callParent();
}};

Ext.create("MyPanel");
```

Comment: a scrollbar will be shown when no place will be available to show all the data. Are you sure you have enough data so that the scrollbars should be shown?